# How to use i3 on CentOS 7 with Gnome?

Tags: centos, gnome, window-manager, i3, xinit

I have a CentOS 7 with Gnome running on my machine. Now I want to use i3 as the window manager. I managed to install i3 but I don't know how to make CentOS 7 use i3 now. I tried to edit `.xinitrc` like so

```
exec i3
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

What do I have to do to use i3 as the window manager on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it running with an unofficial yum repository that has been published here: https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/admiralnemo/i3wm-el7.  Good instructions are included on that page.